# How can perform ROUND.HALFUP in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel only provide below Rounding modes.
[image]

But how can I round a value to HalfUp And HalfDown!??
[image]
https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html

Comment: Try: **Round Half Up** --> `=TRUNC(A2+SIGN(A2)*0.5)` , **Round Half Down** --> `=TRUNC(ROUNDUP(A2*2,0)/2)`

Comment: Why would you want to?  **Round Half Down** will introduce the same bias as does **Round Half Up**?  Better off with a less biased rounding scheme such as **Round Half to Even**.  BTW, Excel `ROUND` does do **Round Half Up**, VBA does **Round Half to Even**.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir, I think `Round Half Up` & `Round Half Down` are required in banks,  may be last year, someone had same query, we they needed this, and informed it was for banking related.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Do you have any documentation for that? **Round Half to Even** is also known as **Banker's Rounding** and is less biased. GAAP indicates that the rounding method should not result in any significant deviation from the unrounded total, so, depending on results, it may be necessary to not round until after computing the SUM, and also necessary to add a footnote to the statement.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir, absolutely that is what I was referring to **Banker's Rounding** I was not able to remember the terminology. Sir I don't have such documentation, but when they informed, I have searched in Wikipedia, to know more about it.

Comment: Thank you both, I just found out that the default rounding method in excel is HalfUp. We can set the cell as Numbers and set the decimal space we need.
We are using this Half UP rounding in Canadian Tax calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following formulas

[image]

---

**Round Half Up**

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=ROUND(A2,0.5)
```

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=TRUNC(A2+SIGN(A2)*0.5)
```

---

**Round Half Down**

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=TRUNC(ROUNDUP(A2*2,0)/2)
```

Comment: For Round Half Up, you can simply use the `ROUND` function on the worksheet.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir, true, while thinking about `HALF ROUND` i missed completely about it. Sir if you wish, you can edit as well.

Comment: I don't edit other's answers. You'd need to change the picture also.

Answer (score 0):

For Rounding Half UP we can set the cell as Number. And also we can change the scaling it is Decimal precision in Number formats.

Right click the cell -> Number formats -> Number.
If the decimal places is set to 2, rounding will be as below,
When 3rd decimal digit is greater than 4, it will be rounded up.
Ex: 2.115 --> 2.12
2.114 --> 2.11

[image]